# Vuejs3 external library undefined funtion

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, fabricjs

I am currently working on a Vuejs3 application with the [fabricjs library](https://github.com/fabricjs/fabric.js) added.
Now I am trying to add an external library called [fabricPublisherTools](https://github.com/mtrudw/fabricPublisherTools) in the application. But the method/function "_registerSnaps" that is being called is somehow "undefined".

The external library gives me the following working example.

```
 <script type="module">
      import {fabricAddSnapper,fabricAddSmartGuides} from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/mtrudw/fabricPublisherTools/dist/fabricPublisherTools.min.js';
      
      fabricAddSnapper();
      fabricAddSmartGuides();
      var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c4');
      var rect = new fabric.Rect({left: 100,top:100,width:150,height:100,fill:'blue'});
      var rect2 = new fabric.Rect({left: 500,top:500,width:150,height:100,fill:'green'});
      var rect3 = new fabric.Rect({left: 400,top:200,width:150,height:100,fill:'yellow'});
      canvas._registerSnaps(canvas._getSmartGuides.bind(canvas));
      rect.doesSnap();
      rect2.doesSnap();
      rect3.doesSnap();
      canvas.add(rect,rect2,rect3);
</script>
```

The way I implemented in Vuejs3 is as follows:

```
<script  setup>
    import { onMounted } from "vue"
    import { fabric } from 'fabric';
    import {fabricAddSmartGuides,fabricAddSnapper,fabricAddUndoRedo} from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/mtrudw/fabricPublisherTools/dist/fabricPublisherTools.min.js';
    
    let canvas;
      
    const setupEditor = () => {
    
      fabricAddSnapper();
      fabricAddSmartGuides();

      canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
      canvas.setHeight(500);
      canvas.setWidth(500);
      canvas.backgroundColor = "#f00";
      canvas.setDimensions({width: 500, height: 500});
    
      var rect = new fabric.Rect({left: 100,top:100,width:150,height:100,fill:'blue'});
      var rect2 = new fabric.Rect({left: 500,top:500,width:150,height:100,fill:'green'});
      var rect3 = new fabric.Rect({left: 400,top:200,width:150,height:100,fill:'yellow'});
    
      canvas._registerSnaps(canvas._getSmartGuides.bind(canvas));
      rect.doesSnap();
      rect2.doesSnap();
      rect3.doesSnap();
      canvas.add(rect,rect2,rect3);
    
      canvas.renderAll();
    
    }
    
    onMounted(() => {
      setupEditor()
    })
</script>
```

It gives me the following error when I try to run it:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'bind')
```

And its about this line:

```
canvas._registerSnaps(canvas._getSmartGuides.bind(canvas));
```

When I console log "_registerSnaps" I see it's undefined which means something has not been appended/added by the library.

I just don't know if I did something wrong when I imported the library that caused the problem.

What exactly am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If bind is what's undefined, have you checked if your problem is with _getSmartGuides since that is what calls the bind() function?

Comment: So I tried to bind "canvas" with _getSmartGuides which does not exist. So something is going wrong during import. But I don't know if its because Vuejs is stopping this or something else.

Comment: Use comment instead of posting it as answer

Comment: Must have 50 reputation to comment. Just getting started @VireshMathad

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to call `fabricAddSmartGuides();`

purely from reading the (fabricPublisherTools) source: `_getSmartGuides` is created in `fabricAddSmartGuides()`. Do you / where do you call `fabricAddSmartGuides` ?

Comment: Yes, something went wrong during copy,paste. But I updated the code. The same "undefined" error still occurs.